# How to center a WPF window on screen from TestComplete tests?

Tags: automated-tests, jscript, testcomplete

I'm automating tests for a WPF application using TestComplete 9 and JScript. How can I position a WPF window to the center of the screen from my test scripts? Is there any built-in function for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TestComplete tests, you can move windows by using the [`Position`](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/61100/) method. You can calculate the centered position of a window based on the desktop resolution (`Sys.Desktop.Width` and `Sys.Desktop.Height`) and the window size (`.Width` and `.Height`):

```js
var wnd = Sys.Process("notepad").Window("Notepad"); // Replace with your window reference

var x = (Sys.Desktop.Width - wnd.Width) / 2;
var y = (Sys.Desktop.Height - wnd.Height) / 2; 
wnd.Position(x, y, wnd.Width, wnd.Height);
```

This is for one monitor. If you have several monitors, adjust the code appropriately. For example, if you have two monitors in horizontal arrangement, use:

```js
var x = (Sys.Desktop.Width / 2 - wnd.Width) / 2;
```

Answer (score -1):

In XAML of Window just use WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"

Comment: I am automating a WPF application and hence need to reposition my app to the center screen.I guess your suggestion deals with making changes to the app code.